# Hoare correctness proof for a recursive definition of multiplication

Tags: logic, correctness-proof, loops, loop-invariants, hoare-logic

Given the program:

```
{y=y0 ^ y>=0}
    z=0;
    while (y>0){
        z=z+x;        (1)
        y=y-1;
    }
{z=x*y0}
```

I am having trouble finding the invariant, I've tried:

- z=xy-xy
- z<=xy
- z=0xy

with/without the precondition as the invariant, but none of my attempts can be used to prove the post-condition. Any help would be greated appreciated!

Moreover, if the code at (1) is changed to z=z*x;, how should I modify my invariant?

Comment: Try `z = xy0 -xy`

Comment: @Dmitry Make an answer?